# Save a selected Item form ComboBox to a variable

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to save the selected Item in a combobox to a string variable. 
This is what I have done but haven't managed to come right. This is in winform.

```
public void Env_PokerBNC_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Env_PokerBNC.Enabled == true)
    {
        DirectoryInfo Translated_Projects = new DirectoryInfo(PokerBNC_Dir);
        string[] FolderNames = Translated_Projects.GetDirectories().Select(d => d.Name).ToArray();
        Build_Combo.DataSource = FolderNames;
    }
}

private void But_PointInternal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //tried Build_Combo.SelectedIndex but no success
    string ComboItem = Build_Combo.SelectedItem;
}
```

I keep getting a string to object error. I have even tried converting the object to a string with no success.

Comment: Is it Winform or Webform?

Comment: Try `string ComboItem = (string)Build_Combo.SelectedItem;`. Looks like you're just missing a cast.

Comment: @LudovicFeltz Winform. Thanks - just updated question

Comment: @GrahamNorton I added the tag. It's helpful for people looking for question in this techno

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Damn. Thanks , Cant believe I overlooked that.

Comment: 'no success' is not a helpful problem description. You should test for a selection actually to exist, btw.

Comment: @GrahamNorton Remember to always read the compiler error message (and to include the error details in your question). The compiler specifically asks you "Are you missing a cast?"

Comment: @GrahamNorton In addition to Ahmed's anwser I personally prefer calling `ToString()` over a cast if I need the string value of an object, even if I am certain the object contains a string value. So it would be: `string ComboItem = Build_Combo.SelectedItem.ToString();`

Comment: You should also check if (Build_Combo.SelectedItem != null) before calling SelectedItem.ToString() in case there were no folder names found.

Comment: @Stefan That's a bad practice, IMO. If the object isn't actually a string, `ToString()` could hide a bug that would otherwise be easily discoverable in the case of casting. The number of debugging questions here on SO where the problem is caused by calling `ToString()` on an object that was thought to be a string but turned out something else is very good evidence that this should be avoided.